# Why is my JTable blank

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Looking round Stack exchange I can't find a good answer to this. Most of the code in similar questions I've seen look massive and bloated where an error could easily creep in; I can't see if I'm making the same mistake or not.

I only have two classes (and an interface), my probelm being is that my JTable is blank:

[image]

Here is my code:

#### Launch the program

```
public class Launcher {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                IViewManager.Util.getInstance();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### Start the ViewManager frame

```
public class ViewManager implements IViewManager {

    JFrame frame = null;
    JTabbedPane myListTabs = null;
    ComicsListPane myComicsListPane = null;

    public ViewManager(){

    //Create and set up the window.
    frame = new JFrame("My List Agregator");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Add the Tabbed pane for lists.
    myListTabs = new JTabbedPane();
    myComicsListPane = new ComicsListPane();
    myListTabs.add(myComicsListPane);
    myListTabs.setTitleAt(myListTabs.getTabCount()-1, "title");
    frame.getContentPane().add(myListTabs);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

#### The Comics List Pane

```
public class ComicsListPane extends JPanel {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5207104867199042105L;
    JTable myComicsTable = null;

        public ComicsListPane() {
                //Create the column names and data
            String[] columnNames = {"Comic Title",
                    "Volume",
                    "Edition",
            "Purchased"};

            Object[][] data = {
                    {"The Amazing Spider-man", new Integer(3),
                        new Integer(679), new Boolean(false)},
                        {"The Amazing Spider-man", new Integer(3),
                            new Integer(680), new Boolean(false)}
            };
            //Create the table
            myComicsTable = new JTable(data, columnNames);
            myComicsTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(750, 110));
            myComicsTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
            myComicsTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(myComicsTable);        
            scrollPane.add(myComicsTable);
            scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 110));
            this.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }
    }
```

I can't see where I've gone wrong, mostly I've copied form the Java Doc Tutorials.

Could someone help point out the error, to a java novice?

Comment: @Razvan The point is to make a table in a scroll pane in a tabbed panel in a frame. Nothing more as of yet.

Comment: What OS are you using? The only reason I ask is that on some operating systems (including Ubuntu, which it looks like you're using) if you press `Alt` + `Print Screen` it will take a screen shot of just the active window.

Comment: @Jeffrey I'm on Ubuntu 12.something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your problem is when you create the `JScrollPane`.

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(myComicsTable);        
scrollPane.add(myComicsTable);
```

The second line here is not needed - you've already constructed the `JScrollPane` with the `JTable`, there's no need to then add it to the `JScrollPane`. Indeed - this is using the `add()` method from `Container`. Exactly why it's causing the behaviour you are seeing is not clear to me without looking at the javadocs/source in more detail.

As an aside, when you're working with GUIs (and indeed, generally) it's best to narrow your code down to the smallest chunks. i.e. a method to create the `JTable` - can that be displayed? Then, a method to wrap it in a `JScrollPane` - does display as you would wish? etc. etc.

Comment: Oops, e must have added the line without thinking.

Comment: adding the table to the scrollPane will remove it from the viewport it has been added to in the constructor :-)

Answer (score 2):

Comment this line:

```
scrollPane.add(myComicsTable);
```

And you should see the table data. To scroll the table you initialized the scroll area with the table - `new JScrollPane(myComicsTable);`. That should be enough to enable scrolling. See [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) on details on scrolling.

Comment: Explaining *why* will probably help the OP more than a magical fix

Comment: Yeah I'd quite like to be able to scroll down the table

Answer (score 1):

Try commenting out this line:

```
scrollPane.add(myComicsTable);
```

Comment: @amaidment provides the rationale for this answer. I also agree with his advise on narrowing down problems. In fact, I found this solution by adding a `main` method to the `ComicsListPane`, creating a `JFrame` and adding a `ComicsListPane` to it.